# Android threads/callbacks

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to create a list of objects (`List<Card>` in my example) where I add objects to this list using json, but the list stays empty. This is my code:

```
public List<Card> readCardsFromJson() {
        final List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader();
                httpReader.setOnResultReadyListener(new HttpReader.OnResultReadyListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void resultReady(String result) {
                                    //Add Card objects to the List<Card>
                                }
                            }
                        });
                httpReader.execute("http://eduphp.khk.be/~r0370877/EnkelExpert.json");
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        return cards;
    }
```

The problem is that the list that I return is empty. I'm pretty sure this is a problem because of the threads that I am using here. I think the return happens before the thread is actually finished, but what do I do in order to fix this?

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that you want to keep things asynchronous, you could return [a `Future`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) through which the caller will eventually get the cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a `Future<List<Card>>` which is non-blocking and will allow you to continue the computation while the HTTP request is being processed:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<List<Card>> futureCards = es.submit(new Callable<List<Card>>() {
    @Override
    public List<Card> call() {
        return readCards();
    }
});
// do some other work ...
// ... and at some point need the List<Card>
List<Card> cards = futureCards.get(); // blocks until the future is completed
```

And the blocking `readCards` method:

```
private List<Card> readCards() {
    final List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    HttpReader hr = new HttpReader();
    hr.setOnResultReadyListener(new HttpReader.OnResultReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void resultReady(String result) {
            //Add Card objects to the List<Card>
        }
    });
    hr.execute("http://eduphp.khk.be/~r0370877/EnkelExpert.json");
    return cards;
}
```